# story id - werewolf biochemist vs alien invasion

Tags: story-identification

I am looking for the name of a science-fiction novel published no later than August 1992. The main character is a very long-lived (centuries) werewolf who is a biochemist. He conceals this by assuming a new identity every few decades. The aliens who conquered Earth are the only ones who can survive FTL without going into suspended animation.

The protagonist is found out by the aliens when he is being interrogated in a room. The aliens give him a list of the names he has used in previous lives and catch him out by slowly turning down the light to a level where normal humans couldn't read. The protagonist doesn't realize the lights are too low until after he denies knowing anything about the names on the list. The novel ends with him sneaking aboard an alien spacecraft and escaping to another world.

Comment: So the werewolf stows away on the alien spacecraft and puts himself into suspended animation? Using some chemicals he cooked up? That's where his training in biochemistry comes in?

Comment: From your resume, I'm not much interested in the story itself but I'd really love to know what did the story author smoked while writing it, 'cause it looks very promising :-D

Answer (score 1):

I was just looking for the same book, and then after reading your summary, it hit me.

I'm going to say *[The Madness Season](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/36161.The_Madness_Season)* by C.S. Friedman.

- Protagonist is a human shape shifter (albeit a vampire).
- Aliens are reptilian and share a single hive mind across the whole species. This is what allows them to endure FTL. They have conquered earth and taken humans to the stars as servants. Also many other alien races.
- Their one vulnerability is periodically one may become disconnected from the hIve consciousness and experience individualiy, temporarily. Such individuals are tolerated by the hive mind but are considered "mad", hence the title.
- The protagonist encounters one in this state and it goes from there, no spoilers please.

Comment: Er... so this isn't the same "Steve"?